# Program crashes when starting Static media player from another class

Tags: android, static, media-player

I have a class which contains a static media-player, but when I try and start the media-player in another activity the program stops working and I cannot see why in my logcat. Here is my first activity, the one from which I am accessing the static media player:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TimerClass t = new TimerClass();
Button start, end, nextclass;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttStart);
    end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttEnd);
    nextclass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttNext);


    //THIS IS WHERE I ATTEMPT TO START THE MEDIA PLAYER, PRESSING THIS BUTTON CAUSES THE PROGRAM TO STOP WORKING
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TimerClass.playr.start();

        }

    });


    end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TimerClass.handler.removeCallbacks(t.getRunnable());
            TimerClass.num =0;
            TimerClass.playr.stop();
        }

    });



    nextclass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent openNext = new Intent("com.example.testingtime.CLASS2");
            startActivity(openNext);

        }

    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here is the class which contains the media player:

```
 public class TimerClass extends Activity {

 public static MediaPlayer playr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    playr = MediaPlayer.create(TimerClass.this ,R.raw.click);
}


static int num =0;
public static Handler handler = new Handler();


    public static Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            playr.start();

            System.out.println("Num is "+num);
            num++;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
        }

    };


    public Runnable getRunnable(){

    return runnable; 
    }
}
```

Here is my Logcat:

```
03-22 23:47:56.699: E/Trace(13723): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-22 23:47:56.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(13723): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043_msm7627a_JB_REL_RB1.2_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
03-22 23:47:56.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(13723): Build Date: 12/10/12 Mon
03-22 23:47:56.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(13723): Local Branch: 
03-22 23:47:56.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(13723): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb1.2
03-22 23:47:56.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(13723): Local Patches: NONE
03-22 23:47:56.969: I/Adreno200-EGL(13723): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
03-22 23:48:02.009: W/dalvikvm(13723): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ce5450)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at com.example.testingtime.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:39)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4129)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17143)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
03-22 23:48:02.019: E/AndroidRuntime(13723):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not sure if there is information on what could be causing somewhere else, is Logcat the Stacktrace?

There are some questions on SO regarding Static media players, I have tried implementing different solutions but nothing is working so far, can anyone see why?

Comment: Please copy and paste your logcat, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `playr` at your `TimerClass` is null - probably your `TimerClass` has not been created before, and therefore it's not initialized - but sharing statics - especially context or UI depending elements between activities is not a good idea anyway.

You should create the MediaPlayer in the Activity where you need it.

Edit: Noticed that your are doing a `new TimerClass()` in your `MainActivity` - instantiating Activities on your own is not a good idea either. You should always use `startActivity` for that - but actually I think you don't really want `TimerClass` to be an Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. All I want to achieve is create a handler runnable which plays a sound every 5 seconds, after a week of many attempts, this is my latest. I need to be able to start and stop the player from more than one class. I am quite confused about the best way to achieve my end goal.

Comment: It was null of course, once I figured out how to initialize I have it somewhat working now, you did figure out my problem! Thank you!